# Building a Neural Network by a constructive variable approach

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-network

I am building a neural network with R's `neuralnet` package.  I am using a constructive variable approach in that I'm adding variables one by one until the RMSE is minimized. As you can imagine, doing this by hand is very time consuming.  I have been training and testing using combinations of 34 different variables.

To start, I train and test 34 models, then keep the model with the lowest RMSE.  I keep the variable that produced the lowest RMSE in the subsequent 33 models.

I'd like a quicker way of doing this than training and testing each of the 33 models by hand but I have no way of knowing how to do this.  Here is some code I've been using:

```
library(neuralnet)
library(rminer)

Data <- data.frame(
  A = sample(1:10),
  B = sample(1:10),
  C = sample(1:10),
  D = sample(1:10))

train <- Data[1:7,]
test <- Data[8:10,]

set.seed(500)
network <- neuralnet(A ~ B + C, 
                 data = train, algorithm = "rprop+", 
                 hidden = c(1), stepmax = 1e6, linear.output = TRUE)
pred <- compute(network, test[,c(2, 3)])
mmetric(test$A, pred$net.result,
    c("RMSE", "MAPE", "COR"))
```

In the end, I'd like to find a way to print the RMSE for each separate varaible.  For example, the first iteration will have 3 RMSE values.  One for `A~B` one for `A~C` and one for `A~D`. Is there a good way to program this?  I don't even know where to begin.

Any help is much appreciated

Basically my idea of a good function would be:

```
test all models separately

return RMSE values for all models
```

Comment: Testing all possible combinations of variables probably won't be the most efficient feature selection method, whether you do it by hand, or inside a loop. Also what is `mmetric()` ?

Comment: @mtoto I understand that it is not the most efficient.  It is still, however, my method of choice.  `mmetric` is part of the `rminer` package.  It is used to calculate error measures.